# Apache - RewriteRule removes url arguments

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try to add a default parameter when using a particular domain name without any additional infos like ht tp:// www.mydomain.com[NOTHINGHERE]

apache keeps removing the parameter, doing some weird split and discarding it although I try many options SDI,QSA,L...

here is the quiet simple rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?s=somehashvalue [QSA,L]
```

here is the log :

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /
pass through /
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] strip per-dir prefix: /somedironmyserver/ ->
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] RewriteCond: input='/somedironmyserver/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='^$' => matched
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] rewrite '' -> '?s=somehashvalue'
split uri=?s=somehashvalue-> uri=, args=s=somehashvalue
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] add per-dir prefix:  -> /somedironmyserver/
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /somedironmyserver/ [IGNORING REWRITE]

init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
pass through /index.html
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] strip per-dir prefix: /somedironmyserver/index.html -> index.html
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.html'
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] RewriteCond: input='/somedironmyserver/index.html' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[perdir /somedironmyserver/] pass through /somedironmyserver/index.html
```

Comment: anyone ? I really need an answer, is there no java guru reading this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the flag `R` to the rewrite rule. `R` signifies Redirect and instructs the server to redirect.

```
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?s=hashvalue [QSA,L,R]
```

You can find more about flags on the Apache site:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: It would be more useful if you added some explanation along with your solution for both current and future readers of your answer.

Comment: yes, well I did not receive any help, and I struggle to understand these myself, so... RewriteRules are weird beasts, that seem to reenter and do things that have nothing to do with the config I put in and I gave up asking on this site for apache questions